# Get Value Difference and Time Stamp Difference from SQL Table that is not Ideal

Tags: sql, python-2.5

This problem is way over my head.  Can a report be created from the table below that will search the common date stamps and return Tank1Level difference?  A few issues can occur, like the day on the time stamp can change and there can be 3 to 5 entries in the database that per tank filling process.

The report would show how much the tank was filled with the last t_stamp and last T1_Lot.

Here is the Data Tree

```
index   T1_Lot     Tank1Level   Tank1Temp   t_stamp       quality_code
30      70517 - 1   43781.1875  120         7/10/2017 6:43  192
29      70517 - 1   242.6184692 119         7/10/2017 0:54  192
26      70617 - 2   242.6184692 119         7/10/2017 0:51  192
23      70617 - 2   44921.03516 134         7/8/2017 14:22  192
22      70617 - 2   892.652771  107         7/8/2017 8:29   192
21      62917 - 3   892.652771  107         7/8/2017 8:28   192
20      62917 - 3   42352.94141 124         7/6/2017 13:15  192
19      62917 - 3   5291.829102 121         7/6/2017 8:06   192
18      62917 - 2   5273.518066 121         7/6/2017 8:05   192
17      60817 - 2   444.0375366 97          7/6/2017 7:23   192
16      60817 - 2   476.0814819 97          7/5/2017 18:09  192
11      62817 - 3   45374.23047 113         6/30/2017 11:38 192
```

Here is what the report should look like.

```
At 7/10/2017 6:43 T1_Lot = 70517 - 1, Tank1Level difference = 43,629., and took 5:52.
At 7/8/2017 14:22 T1_Lot = 70517 - 1, Tank1Level difference = 44,028, and took 5:54.
At 7/6/2017 13:15 T1_Lot = 62917 - 3, Tank1Level difference = 41877, and took 5:10.
```

Here is how that was calculated.

```
Find the top time stamp with a value > 40,000 in Tank1Level, 
Then Find the Next > 40000 in Tank Level. 
Go one index up..
or it could be done with less than 8 hours accumulated
as you can see from the second report line there is data that should be ignored.  
Report that last t_stamp of the series with the T1_Lot.  
Calculate the difference in Tank1Level and report
Then Calculate the t_stamp difference in hh:mm and report.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provided, a self join might work.

```
from yourTable beforeFill join yourTable afterFill on beforeFill.t1_lot = afterFill.t1_lot
    and beforeFill.index = afterFill.index - 1
```